# Can win32 GetCurrentThreadId fail?

Tags: multithreading, winapi

When debugging I found my program in a state indicating that `GetCurrentThreadId` had previously returned `(DWORD)-1`.

Looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28winbase%2FGetCurrentThreadId%29;k%28GetCurrentThreadId%29;k%28DevLang-C%2B%2B%29;k%28TargetOS-Windows%29&rd=true) it seems that the function cannot fail, since there is no section on Error.
Is that correct? Or can it return an error-value in some conditions?

Comment: This is somewhat implausible. I suspect that your diagnostics are wrong.

Comment: Of course it was my fault. Turned out to be a link-error where the project making the lib had another definition than the project using the lib.
I still interested in the question however.

Comment: If that is the case, please delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all currently shipping versions of Windows, `GetCurrentThreadId` cannot fail.

The function simply reads the current thread ID value out of the [thread information block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) and returns it.